# Change size of road label programmatically?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

Can I change the size of `road label` programmatically? In some case, I need to enlarge the `road label` and restore its original size after a short time. Currently, I can achieve it by loading another `map style` and the map will be reloaded completely. Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: Hi, can you help me with mapbox navigation sdk, im kinda lost if you could give me some code sample it would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the map style you are using, you can acquire the road labels layer using `mapboxMap.getLayer()` and then set [the property](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layout-symbol-text-size) making the assumption that it's a symbol layer.